# Android broadcast receiver to get status of installation even app is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hi I am working with android.Firstly I am not familiar with broadcast receiver. I need to create an app in which, if anyone installed my app a broadcast receiver will run which check the installation status like  ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL and android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
.But How can i get these status even my app is closed ?? Is it possible with broadcast receiver ?? Please help me, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, `BroadcastReceiver` can receives broadcasts even if your app is not in foreground, or even if your application's process is not alive.
this can be done by declaring the [receiver within your application's Manifest.xml file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)

when you declare a receiver in the Manifest file - then the system would wake up your application and invoke your receiver if it set with the appropriate intent filter that responding to the broadcast that been sent (in your case -  ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL and PACKAGE_REMOVED actions..)

but unfortunately there are also bad news for you:

**from Android ICS and above - you cannot receive any broadcasts until you application launched explicitly by the user at least once!**

this is due to security reasons Google decided is necessary, to prevent from malicious apps doing staff entirely transparent without  the user launched them at all even once..

so the answer basically is - no!  you can't perform any code and receive any events from your app until it launched at least once.

by the way - you wouldn't received ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL and PACKAGE_REMOVED  broadcasts for your own app that been installed or uninstalled anyway.

by reading your question again, honestly I'm not sure what is that you expects to happend:
 it is no make any sense to "check your application installed status" if it unistalled or not. after all - **if it uninstalled - then it can't run (and perform any code) anyway.**